# cURL Not Working through Proxy with Minecraft API

Tags: php, curl, proxy, file-get-contents, minecraft

I have the following code which checks whether or not the Minecraft user can login to it's services and the output of the cURL requests seems to be "boolean false" for every request when I did my debugging, which is strange because if you enter the URL with the proper values of course into your browser the output is either "Bad login" if the credentials didn't work or it displays the username if it does work.

Here is my following code that isn't working.

Thank you for the help :)

```
function checkLogin($player, $mcpass, $user_sess)
{
//Get Random Proxy
    $resultx = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proxy
WHERE username='$user_sess' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
    $rowx    = mysql_fetch_array($resultx);
    $proxy   = $rowx['proxy'];
//Ok $proxy is the random proxy
    $mcURL   = 'http://login.minecraft.net/?user=' . $player . '&password=' . $mcpass . '&version=13';
    $curl    = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $mcURL);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec($curl);

if (strpos(trim($auth), $player) !== false) {
        echo "$player : $mcpass : Login Valid<BR>";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
var_dump($auth); //Debugging
}
else {
        echo "$player : $mcpass : Login Failed<BR>";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
var_dump($auth); //Debugging
}

}
```